# Why does JMH report such strange times for a simple Quicksort --obviously disproportionate to N * log(N)?

Tags: java, time-complexity, quicksort, jmh

Having an intent to study a sort algorithm (of my own), I decided to compare its performance with the classical `quicksort` and to my great surprise I've discovered that the time taken by my implementation of `quicksort` is far not proportional to `N log(N)`. I thoroughly tried to find an error in my `quicksort` but unsuccessfully. It is a simple version of the sort algorithm working with arrays of `Integer` of different sizes, filled with random numbers, and I have no idea, where the error can sneak in. I have even counted all the comparisons and swaps executed by my code, and their number was rather fairly proportional to `N log(N)`. I am completely confused and can't understand the reality I observe. Here are the benchkmark results for sorting arrays of 1,000, 2,000, 4,000, 8,000 and 16,000 random values (measured with `JMH`):

```
Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt       Score     Error  Units    2N / N ratio          
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray01000  avgt    5     561.505 ±   2.992  us/op              
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray02000  avgt    5    2433.307 ±  11.770  us/op    4.334 
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray04000  avgt    5    8510.448 ±  34.051  us/op    3.497 
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray08000  avgt    5   38269.492 ± 161.010  us/op    4.497 
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray16000  avgt    5  147132.524 ± 261.963  us/op    3.845
```

Obviously the time complexity I observe is very far from `O(n log(n))`, it's almost `O(n^2)`. There may be a tiniest suspicion that the random seed has befallen so unlucky that the values in the arrays happened to be close to the worst case. The probability of this is very close to 0, yet not 0. But the results with a few different random seeds were very similar to that.

And here are the numbers of comparisons and swaps (for 40 iterations with randomly-filled arrays of each size):

```
                     Avr. Comparisons      Avr. Swaps                     2N / N ratio
sortArray01000():           12119.925,       2398.925             
sortArray02000():           26581.600,       5268.525                     2.193, 2.196
sortArray04000():           59866.925,      11451.625                     2.252, 2.174
sortArray08000():          127731.025,      25006.425                     2.134, 2.184
sortArray16000():          273409.925,      54481.525                     2.141, 2.179
```

As everyone can see, the numbers of operations conform the `O(Nlog(N))` law rather well.

It is even possible to suspect that the cost of an individual operation depends on the size of the array we deal with, and I've checked if it's true (with a simple methods that reverse arrays of different sizes) -- and no, as expected, it's not so. The times were very close to `O(n)`.

The only thing I can think of is there's some tricky logical error in my code, but I can't figure it out.

Can anybody help me?

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

/**
 * Why does quicksort take time disproportionate to N * log(N)?
 * Rectified for StackOverflow
 * 21.05.17 16:20:01
 */

@State(value = Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Fork(value = 2)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 10)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 10)
public class QSortBenchmarks {

  private static final int LOOPS_TO_ITERATE = 40; // 40;

  private static final int RAND_SEED = 123456789;
  private static final int RAND_LIMIT = 10000;
  private static final Random RAND = new Random(RAND_SEED); // Constant seed for reproducibility;

  private static int cmpCount = 0, swapCount = 0;
  private static int cmpTotal = 0, swapTotal = 0;

  private static final Integer[] array01000 = new Integer[1000];
  private static final Integer[] array02000 = new Integer[2000];
  private static final Integer[] array04000 = new Integer[4000];
  private static final Integer[] array08000 = new Integer[8000];
  private static final Integer[] array16000 = new Integer[16000];

  @Setup
  public static void initData() {
    cmpCount = 0; swapCount = 0;

    fillWithRandoms(array01000);
    fillWithRandoms(array02000);
    fillWithRandoms(array04000);
    fillWithRandoms(array08000);
    fillWithRandoms(array16000);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, RunnerException {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    initData();

    runJMH(); // Run benchmarks. Comment-out it, if you want just to count comparisons etc.
//    System.exit(0); // If don't want to count comparisons and swaps

    System.out.printf("\nRand seed = %d, rand limit = %d, iterations = %d\n",
                      RAND_SEED, RAND_LIMIT, LOOPS_TO_ITERATE);

    System.out.print("sortArray01000(): ");
    loopOverMethod(qq -> sortArray01000());

    System.out.print("sortArray02000(): ");
    loopOverMethod(qq -> sortArray02000());

    System.out.print("sortArray04000(): ");
    loopOverMethod(qq -> sortArray04000());

    System.out.print("sortArray08000(): ");
    loopOverMethod(qq -> sortArray08000());

    System.out.print("sortArray16000(): ");
    loopOverMethod(qq -> sortArray16000());
  }

  private static void loopOverMethod(Consumer<Object> method) {
    cmpTotal = 0; swapTotal = 0;
    for (int loops = 0; loops < LOOPS_TO_ITERATE; loops++ ) {
      initData();
      method.accept(null);;
      cmpTotal += cmpCount; swapTotal += swapCount;
    }
    System.out.printf("avrg compares: %12.3f,  swaps: %12.3f\n",
                      (double)cmpTotal / LOOPS_TO_ITERATE, (double)swapTotal / LOOPS_TO_ITERATE);
  }

  /**
   * @throws RunnerException
   */
  private static void runJMH() throws RunnerException {
    final Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
        .include(QSortBenchmarks.class.getSimpleName())
        .forks(1)
        .build();
    new Runner(opt).run();
  }

  private static void fillWithRandoms(Integer[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // // Fill it with LIST_SIZE random values
      array[i] = (int)(RAND.nextDouble() * RAND_LIMIT);
    }
  }

  @Benchmark
  public static void sortArray01000() {
    final Integer[] array = array01000;
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public static void sortArray02000() {
    final Integer[] array = array02000;
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public static void sortArray04000() {
    final Integer[] array = array04000;
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public static void sortArray08000() {
    final Integer[] array = array08000;
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public static void sortArray16000() {
    final Integer[] array = array16000;
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
  }

  private static void quickSort(Integer[] array, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi <= lo) return;
    final int j = partition(array, lo, hi);
    quickSort(array, lo, j - 1);
    quickSort(array, j + 1, hi);
  }

  private static int partition(Integer[] array, int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo, j = hi + 1;
    while (true) {
      while (compare(array[++i], array[lo]) < 0) // while (array[++i] < array[lo])
        if (i == hi) break;
      while (compare(array[lo], array[--j]) < 0) // while (array[lo] < array[--j])
        if (j == lo) break;
      if (i >= j) break;
      swapItems(array, i, j);
    }
    swapItems(array, lo, j);
    return j;
  }

  private static int compare(Integer v1, Integer v2) {
    cmpCount++;
    return v1.compareTo(v2);
  }

  private static void swapItems(Integer[] array, int i, int j) {
    swapCount++;
    final Integer tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
  }

}
```

---

### Update 21-05-18 10:08Z

The situation has cleared up. It was `JMH` that showed such strange results that had nothing in common with the actual execution times. A simple hand-made benchmarking with `System.nanoTime()`, for arrays of 10,000, 20,000, 40,000, 80,000, and 160,000 items, showed the following times, :

```
Rand seed = 123, rand limit = 1000000, iterations = 1000
sortArray_010k(): avrg time:    1049.538 mks/op
sortArray_020k(): avrg time:    2282.189 mks/op
sortArray_040k(): avrg time:    4976.079 mks/op
sortArray_080k(): avrg time:   10762.461 mks/op
sortArray_160k(): avrg time:   23115.345 mks/op
```

while the `JMH` results for the same arrays are as following:

```
Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_010k  avgt    5    109.454 ±   0.444  ms/op
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_020k  avgt    5    373.518 ±  17.439  ms/op
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_040k  avgt    5   1350.420 ±  26.733  ms/op
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_080k  avgt    5   6519.015 ±  48.770  ms/op
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_160k  avgt    5  26837.697 ± 926.132  ms/op
```

The figures shown by the hand-made benchmark conform the `N log(N)` quite well, look realistic, and are in good agreement with the observed execution time in seconds. And they are from 100 to more than 1000 times less than the figures shown by `JMH`.

Here's the modified `loopOverMethod()` with which they are obtained:

```
  private static void loopOverMethod(Consumer<Object> method) {
    for (int loops = 0; loops < 100; loops++ ) { // Kinda warmup
      initData();
      method.accept(null);
    }

    long time = 0;
    cmpTotal = 0; swapTotal = 0;
    for (int loops = 0; loops < LOOPS_TO_ITERATE; loops++ ) {
      initData();
      time -= System.nanoTime();
      method.accept(null);
      time += System.nanoTime();
      cmpTotal += cmpCount; swapTotal += swapCount;
    }
    System.out.printf("avrg time: \t%10.3f mks\n", 
                      time * 1e-3 / LOOPS_TO_ITERATE);
  }
```

---

But now another question arises. Why does `JMH` shows such strange results? What is wrong in the way I use it? And obviously I have to revise other project where I use `JMH`. Rather an unpleasant news.

---

### Update 21-05-19 10:08Z

Put it here as an update for the question, since comments don't allow to inser quotes. The comprehensive answer given by Thomas Kleger is absolutely correct. After following his suggestions, I got the following results:

JMH:

```
Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt      Score    Error  Units
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_010k  avgt    5    975.028 ± 23.907  us/op
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_020k  avgt    5   2253.627 ± 94.108  us/op
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_040k  avgt    5   4836.680 ± 80.964  us/op
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_080k  avgt    5  10041.063 ± 27.796  us/op
QSortBenchmarks.sortArray_160k  avgt    5  21232.223 ± 32.008  us/op
```

Hand-made benchmarks:

```
Rand seed = 123, rand limit = 1000000, iterations = 1000
sortArray_010k(): avrg time:    1060.951 mks
sortArray_020k(): avrg time:    2296.533 mks
sortArray_040k(): avrg time:    5021.629 mks
sortArray_080k(): avrg time:   10855.963 mks
sortArray_160k(): avrg time:   23335.923 mks
```

Now the results look quite plausible and I'm completely satisfied with them.

Comment: Caching effects, probably.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I thought about it, that's why I benchmarked arrray reversions with arrays of different sizes. In respect of access to the array items, they are rather similar. No, time was almost exactly linear -- no cachin effects (with these sizes at least)

Comment: Those arrays are just too small, that's why the counting works, but the time measurements do not. Consider trying with millions of elements.

Comment: May be it is because of auto boxing/unboxing? I've tried your example and made arrays as `int` - difference for 16000 array was at about 2 faster for `int` array

Comment: @Alex I'll try. But I doubt -- it may affect (and surely does) the overall performance, but it hardly can affect time-complexity, i.e. how the time depends on the data size. It may 10 times faster both for 10k items and for 20k items, but the ratio will hardly change.

Comment: The issue is your choice of pivot element in partition function. You always take `array[lo]`. If you pick pivot by `array[Math.floor((hi+lo)/2)]` as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme for your input you will see expected runtime complexity. I can not explain why though.

Comment: @FuryFart I don't think so. This algorithm is published exactly in this form in a lot of places, including well-known Sadgewick's book named "Algorithms", which is considered by many people as one of the best. Everywhere they declare the `O(nlog(n))` for average case, and, looking at the code, I can't see why it must not be so.

Comment: First thing I'd do is make the second biggest array the size of the "outermost" processor cache and try again.

Comment: @Alex, by the way, what complexity have you got? How much differ the times for different sizes?

Comment: @m.vokhm well for before 8000 there is no difference. For 8000 difference at about 10-15%

Comment: @m.vokhm In your original post you show the number of comparisons your code performed. The numbers are too high for average. For 1000 items quicksort will have average `1000 * log(1000) = 3000` comparisons. In your figures it is 12000. For 2000 items it should roughly be 6600 comparisons while in your numbers it is 26500. Am I interpreting the numbers right? You must have a bug in your code.

Comment: @FuryFart the N log(N) is only a relative expression, meant for comparison purposes only. It doesn't mean the average number of comparisons is N log(N). In fact, you seem to be using log base 10 - why such an arbitrary log base? Have you tried using log base 2?

Comment: @FuryFart AFAIR, the average number of comparisons is 2n*ln(n). There's a proof in the Sadgewick's book I mentioned (again, AFAIR). For n = 1000, 2,000 ... 16,000 it gives 13,816, 30,404, 66,352, 143,795, and 309,771, respectively. These numbers does not exactly match my results (the exact results slightly vary depending on the rand seed), but are not too far from them.

Comment: I still stand by my answer: your JMH benchmark is not measuring average performance, it is measuring worst case behavior on an already sorted array. Against your assumption the `initData()` method is **not** executed before each call to the benchmark method, but **only once** for each test. See my updated answer below for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @ThomasKläger You are right! Thank you. See the last comment on your answer and the update in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three points work together against your implementation:

- Quicksort has a worst case complexity of O(n^2)
- Picking the leftmost element as pivot gives worst case behavior on already sorted arrays (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot):

> In the very early versions of quicksort, the leftmost element of the partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately, this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays

- Your algorithm sorts the arrays in place, meaning that after the first pass the "random" array is sorted. (To calculate average times JMH does several passes over the data).

To fix this, you could change your benchmark methods. For example, you could change `sortArray01000()` to

```
@Benchmark
public static void sortArray01000() {
  final Integer[] array = Arrays.copyOf(array01000, array01000.length);
  quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}
```

Or you could modify the `@Setup` annotation so that it is executed before each invocation of the benchmark method:

```
@Setup(Level.Invocation)
public static void initData() {
    //...
}
```

---

The `@Setup` annotation takes a parameter that determines when the setup method is executed.

The three levels are (https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/2be2df7dbaf8/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Level.java):

- `Level.Trial`: before each benchmark
- `Level.Iteration`: before each iteration
- `Level.Invocation`: before each execution of the benchmark method

The default level is `Level.Trial` (https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/2be2df7dbaf8/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Setup.java#l54).

What does that mean for your test?

To understand this you have to understand how JMH executes your benchmark:

- It starts a trial for one of your benchmark methods
- during this trial it does 5 warm-up iterations and 5 measurement iterations
- during each iteration it calls your benchmark method in a tight loop until 10 seconds have passed - if your benchmark method takes 500us that means it will be called around 20'000 times during each iteration, or about 200'000 times during full trial

Now with the `@Setup(Level.Trial)` and a benchmark method that sorts the input data in place that means that only the very first call of the quicksort method can show the `O(N log(N))` behavior, all remaining calls operate on the already sorted array and show the worst case behavior of `O(N^2)`.

With `@Setup(Level.Iteration)` the situation is still not much better - now it is the first call of the benchmark method in each iteration that has `O(N log(N))` behavior, the remaining ~20'000 calls per iteration still show `O(N^2)`.

With `@Setup(Level.Invocation)` finally each invocation of the benchmark method (and therefore each invocation of the quicksort) gets its own, unsorted array as an input, and this clearly shows in the results:

```
@Setup(Level.Trial)

1000: 780 us
2000: 3300 us


@Setup(Level.Iteration)

1000: 780 us
2000: 3280 us
4000: 11700 us


@Setup(Level.Invocation)

1000: 58 us
2000: 124 us
4000: 280 us
```

With my proposed change (copying the input array in the benchmark method) I get slightly better results, but these could be due to caching effects:

```
1000: 25 us
2000: 108 us
4000: 260 us
```

Comment: Plus the RANDLIMIT leads to an overproportianal number of values accurring more than once.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have considered your arguments and cannot fully agree with them.  The numbers in the arrays are pseudo-random, it means that the array is not sorted  and it's not the case where the sort with the leftmost item as the pivot shows the worst time.  JMH really  does several passes (I'd even say many passes), but every time it executes the `@Setup` method beforehand, which refills the arrays with random numbers, so the arrays are not sorted when the `sortArray...` methods are invoked.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, but when the `RAND_LIMIT` is greater or of the same order of size as the size of the array, duplicate values are quite rare and don't significantly affect the performance. In any case, such an influence would have manifested itself in the values of the counters, but this does not happen.

Comment: Now I see you are right. And thank you very much for your patience! I did not understand the details about `JMH` that you described so intelligibly. I added `Level.Invocation` to the `@Setup` and the results now look perfectly fine -- see the last update in the question.  Attentive reading of manuals pays off.  It's a good lesson for me, and may be this time I'll learn it finally :) Thank you!